# Dialog popup not displaying rowData react

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, material-ui

I am new to react and working on a table with MaterialUI. It is an editable table and I am trying to have an icon that returns a dialog box. I can get the dialog returned but when trying to pass through the rowData I get nothing. I have tried useState (probably using it wrong) and also trying to pass the data as a parameter.

See code below

```
 export default function MaterialTableDemo() {
 const [state, setState] = React.useState({
 columns : [
 { title: "Program", field: "Program", defaultFilter: "Program" },
 {
  title: 'Program Type',
  field: 'ProgramType',
  lookup: { 1: 'Assignment', 2: 'Auto', 3: 'Default' },
 }, 
],

data : [
{ Program: 'Program', ProgramType: 1 },
{ Program: 'Program 2', ProgramType: 3 },
],
});

 function handleOnClose() {
 setOpen(false)
 }

 function handleOnOpen() {
  setOpen(true)
 //console.log(rowData);
}

const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false); 
const [close, setClose] = React.useState(); 
return (
    <div className="section">
        <h6>filtering</h6>
        <MaterialTable
      columns={state.columns}
      icons={tableIcons}
      data={state.data}
      dataIcon = {rowData => {
        return (
            console.log(rowData),
            React.useState(rowData)
        )
    }}
      detailPanel={rowData => {
          return (
              console.log(rowData), 
              <div>
                  <h2>Expired Time </h2> <br></br>
                  <span>{rowData.ExpireDate}</span>
                  <br></br>
                  <Popup modal trigger={<button>Edit </button>}>
                    {close => <Content close={close} />}
                  </Popup>
              </div>
          )
      }}
      options={{
        filtering: true
      }}
     actions={rowData => {
        return (
            console.log(rowData)
         )},
          [
        { 
          icon: tableIcons.Star, 
          tooltip: 'Popup to Edit',
          onClick: (event, handleOnOpen)

        },
      ]}
      title="Program"
      editable={{
        onRowAdd: newData =>
          new Promise(resolve => {
            setTimeout(() => {
              resolve();
              setState(prevState => {
                const data = [...prevState.data];
                data.push(newData);
                return { ...prevState, data };
              });
            }, 600);
          }),
        onRowUpdate: (newData, oldData) =>
          new Promise(resolve => {
            setTimeout(() => {
              resolve();
              if (oldData) {
                setState(prevState => {
                  const data = [...prevState.data];
                  data[data.indexOf(oldData)] = newData;
                  return { ...prevState, data };
                });
              }
            }, 600);
          }),
        onRowDelete: oldData =>
          new Promise(resolve => {
            setTimeout(() => {
              resolve();
              setState(prevState => {
                const data = [...prevState.data];
                data.splice(data.indexOf(oldData), 1);
                return { ...prevState, data };
              });
            }, 600);
          }),
        }
      }

    />

 <Dialog
  open={open}
  onClose={handleOnClose}
  aria-labelledby="draggable-dialog-title"
>   
  <DialogTitle id="draggable-dialog-title">Edit Program</DialogTitle>
  <DialogContent>
    <DialogContentText>
      Edit Program
    </DialogContentText>
    <div className="group">
      {" "}
      <label label for="ProgramCode"><b> Program: </b></label>
      <input align="right" type="ProgramCode" placeholder="Enter Program Code" align="right" width="300" required></input>
  </div>
  <div className="group">
      {" "}
      <label for="ProgramTypeCode"><b> Program Type: </b></label>
      <input type="ProgramTypeCode" placeholder="Enter Program Type" align="right" width="300" name="CPTC" required></input>
      </div>
  <br></br>
   <button>Save</button>
  </DialogContent>
  </Dialog>
  <br></br>
 </div>
 );
```

}

Comment: Can you show more code? Where 'actions' come from?

Comment: @AlessioMarchi I have updated the code with everything I have. Any input would be great. Thanks!